# Bash CD to directory

Tags: bash, unrar, torrent

I am trying to change the extraction_sudir to a completely unrelated path to the file location (/home/user/downloads/tcomplete/foldername/file.mp4

```
#!/bin/bash
formats=(zip rar)
commands=([zip]="unzip -u" [rar]="unrar -o- e")
extraction_subdir='extracted'

downloadid=$1
downloadname=$2
downloadpath=$3

log()
{
    logger -t deluge-extractarchives "$@"
}

log "Download complete: $@"
cd "${downloadpath}"
for format in "${formats[@]}"; do
    while read file; do 
        log "Extracting \"$file\""
        cd "$(dirname "$file")"
        file=$(basename "$file")
        # if extraction_subdir is not empty, extract to subdirectory
        if [[ ! -z "$extraction_subdir" ]] ; then
            mkdir "$extraction_subdir"
            cd "$extraction_subdir"
            file="../$file"
        fi
        ${commands[$format]} "$file"
    done < <(find "$downloadpath/$downloadname" -iname "*.${format}" )
done
```

I thought it would be as simple as:

```
extraction_subdir='/home/user/extracted'
```

However that seems to just place the unrar'd file in the directory:
/home/user/downloads/tcomplete/foldername/

I am looking at:

```
file=$(basename "$file")
...
file="../$file"
```

Being the cultprit but unsure how to solve this.

Edit:

Solved this my specifying the output in the unrar command e.g.:

```
${commands[$format]} "$file" "$extractedpath"
```

became:

```
${commands[$format]} "$file" "/home/user/extract"
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question is, maybe you can improve your post?

Comment: @Akarienta Sorry i am just trying to change the extraction path that is outside of the downloadpath.

Comment: Associative arrays must be explicitly declared with `declare -A commands='([rar]="unrar -o- e" [zip]="unzip -u" )'`.

Comment: @chepner You pointed me in the right direction: i changed the unrar command to specify the output folder instead.

${commands[$format]} "$file" "/home/user/extract"

Answer (score 0):

You were correct in your analysis.  The issue is that the script assumes that `extraction_subdir` is always within `downloadpath`.

I can't personally test it, but I believe the following will fix the issue:

```
file="${downloadpath}/${file}"
```

It will force the file path to be absolute instead of relative.

Comment: I originally thought this too, i even tried adding the path withouth "Downloadpath" e.g. "/home/user/extract" but i get: 
Cannot open filename.rar
No such file or directory
No files to extract

Comment: @Keelan - That sounds like it's skipping the inner `if` statement entirely.  Make sure you set `extraction_subdir` *and* change the `file="../$file` to the above code and it should work.  The line `if [[ ! -z "$extraction_subdir" ]]` checks if `extraction_subdir` is *not* an empty string, so if you forget to set it, the line `file="${downloadpath}/${file}"` never executes.